# xsl - Apache FOP - Is it possible to allow column breaks but not page breaks?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a project with two columns. There's a block that contains a bit of information at the top and then it contains a table that can be fairly small, but sometimes very large (it's super variable).
I need to allow column breaks within this block when it gets too long, but not page breaks (unless the table is so long that it wouldn't fit otherwise).

I've tried using **keep-together.within-page="always"** but that's apparently too strict, and the table runs down past my margins, and it still ends up starting in the second column, leaving the first column relatively empty (I should mention that there's a little extra data in the first column not attached to the block I'm trying to keep together).

I've tried **keep-together.within-page="1"**, which at least makes it so that super large tables break correctly across the page, instead of running into the margins, but they still end up starting in the second column, leaving the first relatively empty.

I thought that I'd try to explicitly add **keep-together.within-column="auto"**, but that does nothing.

I've been searching the web for an answer for several days, and haven't found much on this. I've already looked at the [W3C specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#keep-together), but they don't seem to clarify this.
Does Apache FOP just treat `.within-page` the same as `.within-column`? It seems like it keeps it within a column regardless of whether I use within-page or within-column; I would think that the two should have very separate functionality.

Here's the output of my `fop -version`

```
FOP Version SVN branches/fop-2_0
```

Example XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                          xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="document">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master 
    master-name="two_columns"
    page-height="8.5in"  page-width="11in" margin-top=".2in" 
    margin-bottom=".1in" margin-left=".2in" margin-right=".5in">          
    <fo:region-body margin-top=".95in" margin-bottom=".5in" column-count="2" />
    <fo:region-before extent=".95in"/>
    <fo:region-after extent=".6in"/>                  
      </fo:simple-page-master>
     </fo:layout-master-set>
     <fo:page-sequence master-reference="two_columns">
     <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" font-family="Times Roman" text-transform="uppercase"
       font-size="8.6pt" >
       <fo:block>Document Title</fo:block>
     </fo:static-content>
     <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" font-family="Times Roman" font-size="7.5pt">
        <fo:block>Document Footer</fo:block>
     </fo:static-content>
     <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-family="Times Roman" font-size="7.5pt">
       <fo:block>
       <fo:block>This is text that appears at the beginning of the document, and never again.</fo:block>
       <fo:block border-bottom="1px solid #000">It takes up space in the first column, and that's it.</fo:block>

        <xsl:for-each select="itemgroup">
        <fo:block keep-together.within-page="1"
            keep-together.within-column="auto">
            <fo:block keep-with-next="always">
                This text that should never be orphaned without the table
            </fo:block>
            <fo:table border="1px dashed #eee">
                <fo:table-header>
                 <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Name</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Date</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Number</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                 </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="item">
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="name"/></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="date"/></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="number"/></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </fo:block>
     </fo:flow> 
     </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can use the example xsl above with this xml (just copy the items over and over to make the first table longer - I didn't want to waste the space on this page):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<itemgroup>
<item>
    <name>Test Person</name>
    <date>September 21, 2016</date>
    <number>42</number>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Test Person</name>
    <date>September 21, 2016</date>
    <number>42</number>
</item>
</itemgroup>
<itemgroup>
<item>
    <name>Test Person</name>
    <date>September 21, 2016</date>
    <number>42</number>
</item>
<item>
    <name>Test Person</name>
    <date>September 21, 2016</date>
    <number>42</number>
</item>
</itemgroup>
</document>
```

Just in case you don't want to have to look it up again (I know I don't), the syntax for fop is:

```
fop -xml sample.xml -xsl sample.xsl -pdf sample.pdf
```

Comment: Hmmm... not sure what this means, but I found on [Apache FOP's site](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-keep-together) that they say `keep-together` is only "partially" compliant with the W3C spec.